# Disabled selected option for others select box when new row added in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am new in jQuery, please help me regarding my problem bellow.

I have dynamic select boxes with dynamic rows, and I want to code these select box like when one option is selected in a select box this should be disabled in all other select boxes by default, however I did this on change of select box, but when I am adding a new row the same option in enabled for new created select box.

**HTML:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      GetDeonmination('Denomination');
    }

    function GetDeonmination(ddlId) {
      $.getJSON("@Url.Action("
        GetCash ")", function(data) {
          var $select = $('#' + ddlId); //$('#down');
          $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            $('<option>').val(value.CashID).text(value.Denominatin).appendTo($select);
          });
        });
    }

    $('.addNewCash').on('click', function() {
      i = rowCounts = $('#tbody tr').length;
      addRow(i);
    });

    function addRow(i) {
      var tr = '<tr class="dataCash">' +
        '<td style="text-align:center">' +
        '<select name="Denomination" class="Denomination" onchange="Calculate(\'Count' + (i) + '\', \'Denomination' + (i) + '\', \'Total' + (i) + '\');" id="Denomination' + (i) + '">' +
        '<option>--Select--</option>' +
        '</select>' +
        '</td>' +

        '<td style="text-align:center"><input type="text" name="Count" id="Count' + (i) + '" class="Count" onkeyup="Calculate(\'Count' + (i) + '\', \'Denomination' + (i) + '\', \'Total' + (i) + '\');" /></td>' +
        '<td style="text-align:center"><input type="text" name="Total" class="Total" id="Total' + i + '" class="Total" /></td>' +
        '<td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align:center"><a href="#" class="removeCash"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" style="text-align:center"></i></a></td>' +
        '</tr>';
      $('#tbody').append(tr);
      GetDeonmination("Denomination" + i);

    };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />


<table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-responsive" id="CashTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td style="background-color: #6600CC; font-weight:bold; color: #FFFFFF; text-align: center;">Denomination</td>
      <td style="background-color: #6600CC; font-weight:bold; color: #FFFFFF; text-align: center;">Count</td>
      <td style="background-color: #6600CC; font-weight: bold; color: white; text-align: center;">Total</td>
      <td style="background-color: #6600CC; font-weight: bold; color: white; text-align: center;">
        <a href="#" class="addNewCash"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbody" class="tbody">
    <tr class="dataCash">
      <td style="text-align:center">
        <select name="Denomination" class="Denomination" id="Denomination" onchange="Calculate('Count', 'Denomination', 'Total')">
          <option>--Select--</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td style="text-align:center">
        <input type="text" name="Count" onkeyup="Calculate('Count', 'Denomination', 'Total');" class="Count" id="Count" />
      </td>
      <td style="text-align:center">
        <input type="text" name="Total" class="Total" id="Total" readonly />
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align:center">

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" in code snippet.

Comment: Mr Jeroen Heier Syntax Error is coming because when click on add row it send request to server to get data for select box please review the code thnx

Answer (score 0):

You can set a flag when onchange event is called and you are disabling the select box. And when you append a new row, then you can set "disabled=true" for the newly created select dropdown.